# Storing filter definition on Solr server

Tags: solr

I have a situation where all my queries have some sub filter queries which are added each time and are very long.
The query filters are the same each time so it is a waste of time sending them over and over to Solr server and parsing them on the other side just to find them in the cache.
Is there a way I can send filter query definition once to the Solr server and then reference it in following queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a static configuration directive in your solr config (`solrconfig.xml`):

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="appends">
        <str name="fq">foo:value</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

.. this will always append a fq= term to the query string before the `SearchHandler` receives the query. Other options are `invariants` or `defaults`. See [Request Handlers and Search Handlers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchHandlers) on the community wiki for more information.